# Hitachi DFT hangs - Causes and workarounds?

Tags: hard-drive, freeze

[Hitachi DFT](http://www.hitachigst.com/hdd/technolo/dft/dftnew.htm) hangs (it gets all the way to "Loading DFT" and hangs with a blinking cursor) when I use it on various computers (the latest computer to hang being a Dell Vostro 1000 laptop) and works on others.

1. What determines when it will hang and when it won't?
2. What similar program can I use (boot CD) that can determine HD health reliably?

Thanks!

Comment: Same thing happening with my Dell Vostro 1720

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this issue with a few laptops -- mostly HP/Compaqs. If the BIOS will let you change the hard drive mode from SATA/ACHI to IDE or 'compatible', this usually works, but don't forget to change it back! Windows doesn't usually like the change.
Alternatives? I've heard that MHDD from www.hddguru.com is good (http://hddguru.com/content/en/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/), but I haven't tried it yet. With an HPaq, I usually just pull the drive and test it in a machine that isn't a complete piece.