# Dell Vostro 1000 audio and wireless NIC drivers

Tags: drivers, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 1000 laptop with a [fresh XP Pro install](https://superuser.com/questions/119794/dell-vostro-1000-w-fresh-xp-pro-installation-running-very-slow). I'm trying to track down the correct audio and wireless NIC drivers. I've used [this](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WW1&catid=-1&dateid=-1&impid=-1&osl=EN&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=VOS_N_1000&hidos=WLH&hidlang=en&TabIndex=&scanSupported=True&scanConsent=False) Dell support driver page, but the drivers it gives for the service tag and XP OS don't work.

Anyone have links to the correct, working drivers?

Comment: What happens when you try the drivers they give you? Do they fail to install, or do they install but not fix the problem? Did you restart first? What does it say in the device manager (devmgmt.msc)?

Comment: @nhinkle: The audio and wireless nic drivers say "This is the wrong OS" (or some language similar to that). I've restarted more than once. After updating to SP3 it shows Audio services with a yellow exclamation by the IDT codec, and a generic yellow by a network controller (which should be the wireless).

Comment: Hm. It looks like there are multiple options under the network drivers section when I visit the page. Are you sure you're downloading for the right wireless card? It seems like what you're doing should work fine... I'm just trying to think of what might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here;

1. When you have Dell search for the service tag it "claims" that the computer is an XPS 1300 instead of a Vostro 1000.
2. I put in the correct service tag and it took me to the correct drivers page. HOWEVER, the ethernet drivers will not work with x64 XP. The WIFI drivers do, but the Broadcom ethernet drivers don't.

Still hunting for the correct ones.

Comment: Note that you do not need 'windows XP' drivers for 'windows XP 64 bit' since the 64 bit version of XP is quite different from the normal windows XP. It is more like 'windows server 2003-light'.