# Typing lag in WinXP

Tags: laptop, lag, typing

I'm working on a Dell Vostro 1000 laptop that has a mysterious lag in typing. You enter keystrokes and it takes a while to show up on the screen. WinXP Pro was [freshly installed](https://superuser.com/questions/119858/dell-vostro-1000-audio-and-wireless-nic-drivers) and the behavior is still here.

Here is the weird part... I've tested the computer with the full Dell diagnostic suite, Prime95 (using UBCD4Win), and Memtest86. Everything checks out as fine. If I run a LiveCD such as UBCD4Win or Ubuntu (9.04?) then there is no typing issue. This is causing me lots of aggravation.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Someone told me to pull out the battery and run it on line power. Sure enough, it cleared up the lag.

I don't understand why or how that causes anything but that it is causing it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a system process it eating up processor cycles.

Do you have the chipset drivers also installed, or did you use the driver supplied by XP Pro?

Just a couple of thoughts.

Comment: @The Chad: Yes, chipset drivers were installed as well.